# How to select xml value using xml starlet

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, xpath, xmlstarlet

How do I retrieve a value using xmlstarlet?

I'm trying to retrieve the Initial value 4.7 from the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GCContextualMethod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.agilent.com/schemas/Analytical/Instrument/GC7890/2006/">
  <method xmlns="">
    <GC PostRunHoldTime="0" AutoPrepRun="UNKNOWN">
      <Inlet DeterminesReadiness="true">
        ...
      </Inlet>
      <Inlet DeterminesReadiness="true" />
      <Column DeterminesReadiness="true">
        ...
      </Column>
      <Column DeterminesReadiness="true">
        <Setpoints Mode="CONSTANT_FLOW">
          <Flow State="ON" InitialHoldTime="0" InitialValue="4.7" PostRunValue="4.7" />
        </Setpoints>
      </Column>
      <Column DeterminesReadiness="false">
```

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
%cd%\resources\XML.EXE sel -t -c "/GCContextualMethod/method[@xmlns=""]/GC[@PostRunHoldTime="0"]/Column[2]/Setpoints[@Mode="CONSTANT_FLOW"]/Flow[@State="ON"]@InitialValue"  %cd%\GC78901.RapidControl.MethodXML.xml
```

Comment: You could also use PowerShell's XML parsing to eliminate the need for the 3rd party executable.  `powershell "([xml](gc GC78901.RapidControl.MethodXML.xml)).SelectSingleNode('//Flow[@State=\"ON\"]').InitialValue"` would get you the InitialValue property of the first Flow element whose State property = "ON".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. The code needs to be able to run on a windows 7 PC so I guess powershell is not an option.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637750(v=azure.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The document element `GCContextualMethod` has namespace uri `http://www.agilent.com/schemas/Analytical/Instrument/GC7890/2006/`.

You need to declare that uri and use the prefix of the declaration in the location step for the document element. Also the filter `[@xmlns=""]` is not needed.

```
XML.EXE sel 
    -N gc=http://www.agilent.com/schemas/Analytical/Instrument/GC7890/2006/
    -t -c
    "/gc:GCContextualMethod/method/....."  
    %cd%\GC78901.RapidControl.MethodXML.xml
```

To test an XPath expression it is always a good idea to see what is returned when running parts of the expression.

Comment: When I use that code it can't load the uri (failed to load external entity)



    %cd%/resources/XML.EXE sel -t -c -n gc=http://www.agilent.com/schemas/Analytical/Instrument/GC7890/2006/ "/gc:GCContextualMethod/method/" %cd%/GC78901.RapidControl.MethodXML.xml

Comment: @JvE010 the params need to be rearranged, `-N` instead of `-n` and inserted before `-t -c`, see my edit.